# Not able to install modules using pip due to HTTPSHandler error Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

I was not being able to installed any module in the cygwin.

I have already:

1. Removed and reinstalled Python
2. Removed and reinstalled openssl and openssl-devel

However, the problems still happens?

```
 $ pip install iplib
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
      load_entry_point('pip==8.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 552, i                                                     n load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2672,                                                      in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2345,                                                      in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2351,                                                      in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <mod                                                     ule>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 1                                                     4, in <module>
    from .compat import sysconfig, detect_encoding, ZipFile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31                                                     , in <module>
    from urllib2 import (Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError,
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
```

Comment: Reinstalling `virtualenv` maybe?

Comment: No Cygwin does not have this package. For the solution provided by RUser98 I have already tried.

Comment: try installing `python-urllib3`. It should provide `HTTPSHandler`

Comment: No, I have installed python-urllib3 it is still not working

Comment: Hi I have found out what is the problem,
I check the dependencies of openssl is libopenssl100
I removed it and reinstalled it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If reinstalling `virtaulenv` doesn't solve your problem, try installing OpenSSl(I do realize you've already reinstalled openssl but doesn't hurt to try it again):

```
yum install openssl openssl-devel -y
```

See [this](http://www.leonli.co.uk/blog/723/solve-python-importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler).